# getting the value of python function from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, bottle

I'm wondering if there is a way to pass a python dictionary to javascript?

okay, I'm using `bottle` to have a web framework and my setup is something like this:
[image]

in **runTheApp.py** I have:

```
# importing general packages
import bottle

@bottle.route('/')
def index():
  return bottle.template("index")

@bottle.route('/static/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
  return bottle.static_file(filename, root="./js")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  bottle.run(host="localhost",port=8080,debug=True,reloader=True)
```

and my python dictionary that I want to access from is in **myData.py**:

```
def get_data(): 
    return {"Name":"James","City":"KL"}
```

I can access to python from **index.tpl**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us">
%import myData
%data = myData.get_data()
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="greeting"> Hi {{data["Name"]}} from {{data["City"]}} </p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/changer.js"></script>
</html>
```

but I want to access to it from **changer.js**, in there I have:

```
var greeting_p = document.getElementById("greeting");
var wishing_p = document.createTextNode("hope you are doign well.");
greeting_p.appendChild(wishing_p);
```

How can I get the python dictionary from javascript?
is it a good idea doing this? as in is it secure and best practice?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an AJAX method to let the bottle app return the data in JSON format (or XML, if you're comfortable with that) and the returned value can then be manipulated by the JavaScript function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I figure that out, there is a feature in the bottle to pass the dictionary right away when calling the template and no need to use Ajax.

Comment: but if I want to call it from Javascript, Ajax is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figure that out, here is the example:

Passing dictionary to the template like so:

```
@bottle.route('/')
def index():
  data = [{"user":"Bernard"}]
  return bottle.template("index", data=data)
```

and in the template just read it like so:

```
console.log("{{data['user']}}")
```

also, to call it with Ajax from javascript like what Josh English said, make a POST function and send the dictionary as JSON like so:

```
@bottle.route('/get-user-info', method="POST")
def get_user_data():
    data = [{"user":"Bernard"}]
    retun json.dumps(data)
```

And call Ajax in javascript like so to get the JSON file:

```
// getting the data
var result = $.ajax({
        url: "/get-user-info",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: true,
});
```

Hope that help anyone that has the same problem.